# How to Validate an eCheck in Authorize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, payment-processing

I am working on c# project where I want to integrate Authorize.net payment gateway.

I have some below doubts:-

```
1) can we authorize an eCheck before processing(valid or not), if yes then how?

2) As in below image I have check number, is it necessary to pass it along with Account and Routing number while creating a customer profile with eCheck?

3) Characters limit(min and max) for
    1) Account number
    2) Routing Number
    3) Credit/Debit card number(in case of Card payment)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No , you cannot authorize echeck accounts before processing. If you want make sure whether it's a valid account or not then you need to charge them a nominal amount, provided you have the customer's authorizaton to do so.Also you must refund the amount as soon as it got credit in your account.

2)There is no need to pass the check number while creating the customer profiles. You do not need it even while processing credit or debit transactions. All you need in Account Number, Routing Number, DP's name etc.. The required fields are clearly marked in the API method.

3)Account Number - varies from bank to bank.
  Routing Number - must be a 9 digit number.
  Credit Card Number - 13- 16 digit number.depends on bank again.

Comment: thanks @Ramoji, as you said account number varies bank to bank so what should I use to pass minimum and max length 8-15?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot give you a range of number of digits for bank accounts in USA. I too got stuck there and just made the field to accept only digits and not more than 16.

Comment: Ok, right now I am working on test mode(sandbox account), when I want to use live mode mode should I just replace this keyword "Sandbox" with "Production" in my code or is there any other changes as well?